# Safari see times in history

Tags: macos, safari, high-sierra

I use Safari on my MacBook.

I'm disappointed the History page doesn't show times a site was loaded.

How can I view the times that a website was visited?

Other answers on this site don't work for me on High Sierra, the path `~/Library/Caches/Metadata` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

On High Sierra the path is: `~/Library/Safari/History.db`

I believe it's a SQLite database. The timestamps are stored in native Core Data format so you'll need to convert to something human readable (e.g. http://andrewbranch.github.io/coretime/).